# Preserving quotation marks using bash history

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

You run a command like `echo "hi world"`.

```
hi world
```

Then you run `echo !!` to try to display the command you just ran.

```
echo echo "hi world"
echo hi world
```

The first line outputs the command that will run. The second line represents the actual output.

How do you run the command so that it outputs `echo "hi world"` just as you input in the first place?

Comment: Just use `!!`? ...

Comment: Your suggestion results in `"hi world"` whereas the intended result would be, `echo "hi world"` which was the command originally entered.

Comment: If you want to *examine* the command you just ran, invoke `history 2`.

Comment: You can print previous commands in bash with `fc`. For just the last command without history numbers etc, use `fc -ln -1 | sed $'s/^\t //'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Use `fc` instead.

```
fc -ln -1 | sed $'s/^\t //'
```

Answer (score -3):

The right answer was given above by DavidPostill:

[image]

Comment: The last line output should read `echo "hi world"` and not `hi world`. Feel free to suggest edits to clarify my question.

Comment: @IliasKarim: This is a real screenshot of real execution. Fix what?

Comment: @IliasKarim: I think you haven't understood how shell substitution works. It is only simple string substitution, where `!!` just stands for the text of the last command. So doing `!! (enter)` just repeats the last command. You can also do `!! more parameters` to extend the last command with more. Try it.

Comment: it says `hi world` when it should say `echo "hi world"` on the last line before your blank prompt.

Comment: This is only when the command is `echo !!`, where the `!!` is replaced by `echo "hi world"`. To better understand the subject, see for example [15 Linux Bash History Expansion Examples You Should Know](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/).